# How does Blocktrail encrypt its wallet backup information which is in PDF file?

Tags: encryption, blocktrail

I have *BTC.com Bitcoin Wallet Recovery Backup Sheet* and i do not like the idea behind Blocktrail's wallet process because it doesn't give you an option to save your seed or private key but it just sweeps the wallet.
So wanted to develop a tool that saves the seed or private key, All i could find in the SDK source code is that they use AES256GCM with Salt and IV.
But i wanna know how do they get to output Encrypted Primary Seed.